# Why is comma used in this sentence?

Tags: commas

Why is comma used in this sentence?

> Hyena crept slowly round, making the most of his spotted brown camouflaged fur against the brownish stems of grass.

Comment: What do you know about comma usage? Do any of those reasons seem to fit here? Please [edit] your question to show us what you already know and what effort you've already made to answer it yourself, or it will be closed for lack of research.

Answer (score 0):

This is sometimes called a [bracketing comma](https://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/comma/bracketing). In this case, "Hyena crept slowly round" is a complete sentence/clause on its own. The additional text can be called (as in the page linked to) an "interruption", and is marked off with a comma.

(Also note that, if you were reading this aloud, you'd most likely pause where that comma is, indicating that it's something in addition to the main part of the sentence.)

Answer (score 0):

"Making the most of..." is a [non-restrictive](https://academicguides.waldenu.edu/writingcenter/grammar/clauses) participial phrase. These are usually separated from the main sentence by a comma.